# Magento - Retrieve custom attribute LABEL in cart with config.xml

Tags: magento, attributes, cart

I have a custom attribute that i need to display in the shopping cart. The attribute is a Dropdown like so:

```
Attribute Code : section
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Dropdown
Options:
    ID/VALUE = 67 LABEL = warehouse
    ID/VALUE = 69 LABEL = showroom
    ID/VALUE = 70 LABEL = stockroom
```

To display this i have a custom module with my config.xml like so:

```
<global>
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <section/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

And in the cart i can call:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getSection();
```

This returns the ID/VALUE of the attribute (i.e 67) but i want to be able to get the LABEL (i.e warehouse)

I know i can get a label from the id like so:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("section");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText("67");
}
```

But I want to get the label through my module so i can cutout extra databae queries and having to load the product model again. My cart can have upwards of 20+ items per order so using this last approach can slow it down slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('section')` instead, which is clearer, but I have not looked into the performance. I would think that if you are loading the products in a collection that includes the attribute already then it will not require separate database calls per product/attribute.

Comment: Spot on. Performance doesn't seem to have been hit either. Thank you

Comment: If instead of the AttributeText you wanted to get the StoreLabel what would you do? I can't seem to get the StoreLabel without the page dying when it hits my code. `$_item->getProduct->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getStoreLabel();`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item object. If so, you can try the following snippet:

```
$_resource = $_item->getProduct()->getResource();
$optionValue = $_resource
    ->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getProduct()->getId(), 'section', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$optionLabel = $_resource
    ->getAttribute('section')
    ->getSource()
    ->getOptionText($optionValue);
```